# Запрос в формате JSON в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Проблема в очень долгом выполнении php, в файле создается JSON объект и только, а по времени занимает 30 секунд для таблицы в 7000 строк. Подскажите, что в формате создания запроса не так ?
Прикладываю скриншоты mysql и вывод JSON

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sensor") or die ("Connection error");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{
$temp[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(float)$row['value']);
$temp1[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(float)$row['value1']);
$temp2[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(int)$row['value2']);
$temp0= array($temp,$temp1,$temp2);
}
echo json_encode($temp0);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в цикле вы перезаписываете `$temp0` снова и снова – возможно, это ест память и время. Результат на выходе вас устраивает?

Comment: А еще стоит попробовать по-профилировать. Есть чувство, что `json_encode` может "жрать" много процессорного времени для больших структур данных

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$data = mysql_query("SELECT 1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS ts, value, value1, value2 FROM sensor") or die ("Query error");

header("Content-type: text/json");

$V0 = $V1 = $V2 = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    $V0[]= array( $row['ts'], (float) $row['value']);
    $V1[]= array( $row['ts'], (float) $row['value1']);
    $V2[]= array( $row['ts'], (int)   $row['value2']);
}
mysql_close($con);

echo json_encode( array( $V0, $V1, $V2), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Если всё так же медленно, то, как предложил @Dmitry_Simushev, возможно тормозит кодирование в JSON, и тогда можно попытаться обойти его, прямо собирая текстовую строку.

**Второй вариант** – можно попробовать собирать JSON «вручную»:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT 1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS ts, value, value1, value2 FROM sensor") or die ("Query error");

$V0 = $V1 = $V2 = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $V0 .= sprintf( '[%d,%f],', $row['ts'], $row['value']);
    $V1 .= sprintf( '[%d,%f],', $row['ts'], $row['value1']);
    $V2 .= sprintf( '[%d,%d],', $row['ts'], $row['value2']);
}
mysql_close($con);

header("Content-type: text/json");
echo printf( '[%s,%s,%s]', rtrim($V0,','), rtrim($V1,','), rtrim($V2,','));
```

Comment: Я безгранично рад, спасибо огромное Вам и Dmitry_Simushev за совет. Все работает отлично, первым способом за 40мс, а вторым за 20мс.

Answer (score -3):

Здесь стоит выполнить всё запросом. Т.к. вы получаете данные и через цикл проходите через КАЖДУЮ строчку. Т.к. строк много, то и время выполнения скрипта большое.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, что именно Вы предлагаете ?

Comment: Возможно ли, выполнить след. действия в запросе?


`$temp[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(float)$row['value']);
$temp1[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(float)$row['value1']);
$temp2[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(int)$row['value2']);
$temp0= array($temp,$temp1,$temp2);`